# Count and distinct in mysql (comma separated data in table)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the details from mysql database.

My table have location field.
Data is like below

```
Location
India
UK,Finland, India
USA, NZ, AUS, Spain
```

I am trying to get the count for each location.

```
select count(distinct location) from posting
```

This is the query i have written at the moment for testing purpose. It return me count.

I want to get the details like below.

```
India -2
UK - 1 
Finland -1
USA - 1
```

Something like that.

**Note**  Please ignore dash as this is just to show you what i want.

Please advise me as i am not good in database.

Comment: `select location, count(distinct location) from posting` should work.

Comment: Thanks for down voting guys. i would love to see explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be storing multiple values in a single columns.  Delimited strings are *not* the right way to store values in SQL.  The proper way is a junction table.

If I assume that you have a list of locations, then you can do:

```
select l.location, count(*)
from location l join
     posting p
     on find_in_set(l.location, p.location) > 0;
```

If you don't have such a table, I would recommend that you focus on fixing your data structure first, rather than trying to get such a query to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i am using select2 to select multiple location and after that i save them in database.

Comment: One error in your query. ( from location l join) it should be (from posting l join)

Comment: i run the query but it is only returning single location. Not all of them. Any advise?

Comment: I was writing this @Gordon, you are just impossible to beat :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(location),location FROM posting;
```

Try this one out. It will give you a similar output.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The first column can only be 0 or 1.